# Expand a window beyond Windows limitation

Tags: scripting

I try to setup UltraMon with a really big width and height for my Safari on Windows.

See capture : http://cl.ly/de21e9cd2cf4f265efc4

The problem is that the width and height seems to have a max value that I would like to change.

I want UltraMon not to change my width and height, even if they are bigger than the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't allow that, according to the developers of UltraMon.
See http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/forum/messages.asp?tmpl=UltraMon&Topic=10795#39510